# I would like to be able to use Console.WriteLine() and Console.ReadLine() in the same line

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that will act like a terminal, however, I'm having some issues with it. I would like to be able to prompt the user for a command and have the user be able to type in the command in the same line in the terminal, but I don't know how to do that. Every time I try, the prompt, telling the user to type shows up in one line and my 'ReadLine' is the line under it.

For example, I want it to look like this:

user1> (user types command here)

my code goes like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("user1>");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
```

and then I'll of course have more code after that but that's the trouble spot (getting the two on the same line in the console)

But it always compiles as this:

user1>
(user types command here)

If someone could come up with an example of what I'm supposed to do in this situation, that would be great help.

Comment: You should use Console.Write("user1>"); instead of  Console.WriteLine("user1>"); , good luck